# Socket.io-netty and socket.io v0.7 - forbidden

Tags: java, socket.io, netty

I'm using this lib https://github.com/ibdknox/socket.io-netty.
And with new socket.io catch error with [this line](https://github.com/ibdknox/socket.io-netty/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ibdknox/socket_io_netty/WebSocketServerHandler.java#L142) . Looks like socket io doesn't send required headers(WEBSOCKET_PATH 137 line, FLASHSOCKET_PATH 139 line) and location was null.
How do I see, browser trying to get url  http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/1/?t=1331464323415&jsonp=0 and doesn't send any needed headers - [here](http://pastie.org/3570082) headers that were sent.

What do I need to fix the problem? I can't understand -_-

This is javascript clientside code:

```
var chat = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080')

      chat.on('connect', function () {
        chat.emit('hi!');
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket.io-Netty does not support socket.io protocol higher than **0.6**. You can try to use  another implementation of socket.io server -
https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio. It supports latest protocol of socket.io.